# Search Results Web results PHP MySQLi Prepared Statements 0 results

Tags: php, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a small problem with a function that needs to check if there is a row with a specific ID.
The database contains a row, but the function does not display anything.

```
    public function hasInvoice(int $invoice_ID)
{
    var_dump($invoice_ID);
    $stmt_check = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Invoice` WHERE 'OrderID'=?");
    var_dump($stmt_check);
    $stmt_check->bind_param("i", $invoice_ID);
    $stmt_check->execute();

    if ($stmt_check->num_rows > 0) {
        var_dump("Invoice already exist");
        return true;
    }
    var_dump("Invoice not exist");
    return false;
}
```

[image: Invoice DB]
Does anyone have any idea what I did wrong in the content of the function, that it seems to be correct, but it still doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to put single quotes around `OrderID` or backtick characters? I believe that is your problem.

Comment: No problem in quotes, the problem is that it does not display my row in the database with this ID.

Comment: I only need to check if there is a row with this ID and that's it.

Comment: If `OrderID` is the name of your column, you better not put quotes around it. As your SQL is written it will return *every* row from your Invoice table if and only if `$Invoice_ID` is equal to the string literal 'OrderID'. But of course, that won't be the case since your are binding it as an integer. You can lead a horse to water but you can't make hiim drink.

Comment: Okay, so what's the mistake?
that I put the quotes in OrderID or which?
because even if I remove the quotes from OrderID, this doesn't work anyway

Comment: Yes, the single quotes is an error as I indicated in my last comment. You can put column names within backticks, but that's only necessary if the name has special characters such as spaces. Make sure `$invoice_ID` has the value you expect (that is, `65`). Then after call to `execute()`: `$result = $stmt_check->get_result(); $num_rows = $result->num_rows;`

Comment: Alternatively, following call to `$stmt_check.execute()` just insert: `$stmt_check.store_result();`, which I suppose is even simpler. Then your `$stmt_check.num_rows` will return correct value.

Comment: `bind_result($invoiceID, $invoiceName);`
`$stmt_check->execute();`
`$stmt_check->fetch();`
`$stmt_check->close();`
`if (isset($invoiceID))`

and this would be another alternative. Thanks for the help